# Como carregar uma lib redis (lua) usando o comando 'docker exec'?

Tags: docker, lua, redis

Estou tentando carregar uma lib no redis usando 'docker exec', mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> ERR Missing library metadata

Comando usado:

```
docker exec redis-db_1 redis-cli -a [senha] FUNCTION LOAD "$(cat [path]\ZRANDSCORE.lua)"
```

Código [ZRANDSCORE.lua]

```
#!lua name=ZRANDSCORE

local function zrandscore(KEYS, ARGV)

    local set = redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
    local langth = table.getn(set)
    local member = set[math.random(1, langth)]
    redis.call('ZINCRBY', KEYS[1], ARGV[3], member)
    return {member, langth-1}

end

redis.register_function('ZRANDSCORE', zrandscore)
```

Na primeira linha observe que os metadados são informados como [instruído na documentação](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/functions-intro/#loading-libraries-and-functions):

```
#!<engine name> name=<library name>
```

tanto que, quando executo esse mesmo código direto no redis obtenho sucesso
[saída da execução](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w2rz.png)

Comment: Existe algum motivo para usar o `cat`? A barra invertida (\) antes do `ZRANDSCORE.lua` está correta?

Comment: Sim, o comando **FUNCTION LOAD**  espera uma String contendo o script. Por isso uso **$(cat )** pra ler e direcionar a saída. Com relação a barra, é isso mesmo. @GuilhermeNascimento